# Implicit convertion sql nvarchar into R int during loading data

Tags: sql-server, r

I have variable in SQL in nvarchar format like this - `'001'`.
when I load data to R I've got this variable as integer `1`.
How can I avoid the conversion to int?

```
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};
 Server=XXXX; 
 Database=XXXX;
 Uid=XXX; Pwd=XXXX; 
 trusted_connection=yes",
 DBMSencoding="UTF-8"`
)

Customers <-
  sqlFetch(dbconnection,"VW_CUSTOMERS_ACTIVE")%>%
  left_join(Customers_Group,  by = "Customer_group")
```

Comment: NVARCHAR is a text type, not a format. It corresponds to UTF16, not UTF8. What is the table's schema? Is the field (not variable) really a string with the characters `001` ?

Comment: BTW you can't use a username, password *and* request Windows authentication at the same time. Never mind the wrong encoding? Is this what you really tried? It would seem that RODBC ignored every setting except the server and database

Comment: Sorry for lack of knowledge of definitions and unprofessional expression, i'm very new to this...     In SQL table I have column: Column_name (nvarchar(3), null)   . The values in this column can be : '001', '01', 'nz'.  I need to filter 'nz' and   load this column to R. But values I'd got in R were 1 and 1 as integer data types.